# Using Flyway and TOAD to compile the same Oracle code

Tags: oracle, toad, flyway

As a company we are looking to use flyway to manage our Oracle database migrations, and as a tool it looks like it'll be excellent for our needs. I've looked further into how it'll fit into our development processes and have run into a problem which I have not been able to resolve.

We'll be setting up an additional database instance which we'll be using for Continuous Integration, and Automated Testing. We'll use flyway to release our DB Application to this instance. To allow for multiple versions of the database application we'd like the ability to release our DB code to different schemas. So, if we had a schema called SCOTT, then we may want to release the code to SCOTT_RM, SCOTT_CI, SCOTT_V5, etc.

We can manage this in flyway by using placeholders to mimic the syntax required for variable substitution in Oracle, i.e.

```
flyway.placeholderPrefix=&&
flyway.placeholderSuffix=.
```

This works well when running through Flyway, or SQL*Plus. Our package declaration would look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE &&SCHEMA_SCOTT..pa_package AS
```

However, the problem lies when a developer is working within TOAD and they want to compile the code directly into their own schema. When this is run as a script (F5), or run from SQL*Plus then the variable is flagged as requiring a value, allowing the code to be compiled into the correct schema. However, when compiling this code (F9) in TOAD the variable isn’t recognised and we receive the oracle error “ORA-04050: invalid or missing procedure, function, or package name”.

It’s not practical to use F5 to compile the code, because when there is a compile error it doesn’t jump to the offending line, as happens when F9 is pressed. e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE &&SCHEMA_SCOTT..pa_package AS
   lv_num NUMBER();  -- Compile Error
END;
/
```

Interestingly I looked Oracle’s SQL Developer and found that these variable substitutions work there as I’d hope.

Does anyone know how we might resolve this problem in TOAD?

Comment: There's a division in the code that sends PL/SQL DDL down one path and all other statements down another when executing using F9. PL/SQL DDL is bypassing the substitution variable logic incorrectly. The issue will be logged. I don't see any way to workaround it other than Execute Script (F5).

Comment: Thanks Michael. It's always nice to know that we were facing this problem due to the tool, and not because we were doing something wrong.

Comment: I'm surprised this has just come up. It's the first I've heard of it and definitely a miss.